# 'margin-bottom' not visible for DIV with auto height

Tags: css, html

I have a container DIV (block2) that has 2 child div (headline and content) and the container's height should adapt to these child tags.

However, the **bottom-margin** specified for the container div doesn't appear as it's height is dynamic.  I don't have any floating elements (tried with clear:both style div as well, didn't work).

Here is my CSS:
('details' is the table inside 'content')
Please pardon me for the clumsy code. New to CSS.

```
#block2 {
width: 91%;
height: auto;
background: #c9b18b;
margin: -1px auto 0px auto;
padding-top: 1px;
}

#headline {
background: #70a3be;
height: 300px;
margin: 13px 13px 12px 13px;
}

#headline h1 {
float:right;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-right:55px;
font-size: 425%;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: right;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
color: #005480;
}

#content {
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 300px;
margin: -1px 13px 13px 13px;
padding-top: 1px;
}

#details
{
width: 97%;
margin: 50px 0px 15px 15px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

#details td {
padding: 10px;
}

#details tr.odd {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: x-large;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #d9e6ee;
color: #005480; 
border-top: 4px solid #6578b2;
border-bottom: 4px solid #6578b2;
}

#details tr.even {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:x-large;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #005480;
}

#details tr.header {
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.6em;
}

#details a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #005480;
}

#details td.region {width: 13%;}

#details td.city {width: 17%;}

#details td.topic {width: 40%;}

#details td.date {width: 15%;}
```

How do I get the bottom margin of block2 to appear? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: setting overflow:hidden; on #headline will give it the right dimensions since you are floating an element inside of it. #block2 might need display:block; as well.

Comment: Shan, tried doing that just now. Added overflow:hidden to #headline and display:block to #block2. Still, no bottom margin.

Comment: Set `overflow:hidden` to the `#block2` http://jsbin.com/acucUGA/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I may be missing something but it worked for me... I don't mean to sound condescending but you know there is 0px set for the bottom margin right? When i change it with overflow and display block on those elements it's working. All in the fiddle of course.

Comment: OMG! Apologies. I set it 0 while playing around and forgot to reinstate it. Thanks Shan and Hieu! Working perfect! It would be great if you could share the reason why this happened? I mean, I tried clearing floats at the end of block2. Why didn't that work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

insert your container inside another `<div id=#wrapper>` and give separate css again to `#block2 {margin-bottom:2px;}`